# How to approach this question on choosing balls from a box?

Tags: probability

> A box contains $2n$ balls of $n$ different colors, with 2 of each color. Balls are picked at random from the box with replacement until two balls of the same color have appeared. Let $X$ be the number of draws made.
>
> a) Find a formula for $P(X > k)$, $k = 2, 3, ...$

$P(X>k) = 1 - P(X\le k) = 1- (P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+...P(X=k))$

So I manaully find $P(X=2)$, $P(X=3)$, $P(X=4)$, ... and try to find a pattern to make an equation?

**Edit 1:**

For each $n$ color, trials = 2, success rate = $\frac{2}{2n}$, # of needed success = 2, ordering doesn't matter, with replacement

$P(X = 2) = n \cdot Binomial(2, \frac{2}{2n}) = \binom{2}{2} (\frac{2}{2n})^2(1-\frac{2}{2n})^0$

For each $n$ color, trials = 3, success rate = $\frac{2}{2n}$, # of needed success = 2, ordering doesn't matter, with replacement

$P(X = 3) = n \cdot Binomial(3, \frac{2}{2n}) = \binom{3}{2} (\frac{2}{2n})^2(1-\frac{2}{2n})^1$

For each $n$ color, trials = 4, success rate = $\frac{2}{2n}$, # of needed success = 2, ordering doesn't matter, with replacement

$P(X = 4) = n \cdot Binomial(4, \frac{2}{2n}) = \binom{4}{2} (\frac{2}{2n})^2(1-\frac{2}{2n})^2$

For each $n$ color, trials = 5, success rate = $\frac{2}{2n}$, # of needed success = 2, ordering doesn't matter, with replacement

$P(X = 5) = n \cdot Binomial(5, \frac{2}{2n}) = \binom{5}{2} (\frac{2}{2n})^2(1-\frac{2}{2n})^3$

$$P(X>k)=1-(n \cdot \sum_{i=2}^k \binom{i}{2} (\frac{2}{2n})^2(1-\frac{2}{2n})^{i-2})$$

**Edit 2:**

Last ball has to be a color already chosen.

For X = 2, no restrictions on the 1st ball, 2nd ball must be a color already chosen.

$P(X = 2) = \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2}{2n}$

For X = 3, no restrictions on the 1st ball, no restrictions on the 2nd ball, 3rd ball must be a color already chosen.

$P(X = 3) = \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{4}{2n}$

For X = 4, no restrictions on the 1st ball, no restrictions on the 2nd ball, no restrictions on the 3rd ball, 4th ball must be a color already chosen.

$P(X = 4) = \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{6}{2n}$

$$P(X > k) = 1 - (\sum_{i=2}^k \frac{2^{i-1}}{2n})$$

**Edit 3:**

Last ball has to be a color already chosen **AND** other balls must be different!

For X = 2, no restrictions on the 1st ball, 2nd ball must be a color already chosen.

$P(X = 2) = \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2}{2n}$

For X = 3, no restrictions on the 1st ball, 2nd ball must be different from the 1st ball, 3rd ball must be a color already chosen.

$P(X = 3) = \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n-2}{2n} \cdot \frac{4}{2n}$

For X = 4, no restrictions on the 1st ball, 2nd ball must be different from the 1st ball, 3rd ball must be different from the 1st and 2nd ball, 4th ball must be a color already chosen.

$P(X = 4) = \frac{2n}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n-2}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n-4}{2n} \cdot \frac{6}{2n}$

$$P(X>k)=1-(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2(n-1)}{n^2} + \frac{3\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)}{n^3} + ... + \frac{(k-1)(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-(k-2))}{n^{k-1}})$$

**Answer from Textbook:**

> $\frac{2n-2}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n-4}{2n} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{2n-2(k-1)}{2n}$

Comment: That sounds like a very reasonable way to start.

Comment: "try to find a pattern to make an equation?" why don't you try it out and see if it works?

Comment: (+1) for adding the steps in detail. Very few users do so, even after being asked to.

Comment: The last $(k-2)$ in Edit 3 should be $(n - (k - 2))$ or $(n - k + 2).$

Comment: @DavidK Okay, I changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interpreted the problem as if you pre-selected one of the colors before drawing any balls and require to draw two balls of that color, for example if there are red balls you might choose red and then you will stop only when you have drawn red twice. I would interpret it differently--if *any* color is drawn that has been drawn before, you stop. By the pigeonhole principle the maximum possible value of $X$ is $n +1.$

The textbook apparently interpreted the question the way I did.

For example, you draw one ball and observe its color. 
Put it back and draw again.
In order for $X > 2,$ the second ball you draw must be different from the first. There are $2n - 2$ such balls, so 
$P(X> 2) = \frac{2n - 2}{2n}.$

If the second ball is a different color from the first, then on the third draw there are now only $2n - 4$ balls that are different from any color already drawn.
(Either of the two previously seen colors is a match.)
To have $X > 3$ you must avoid a match on draw number $2$ and again on draw number $3,$ so
$P(X > 3) = \frac{2n - 2}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n - 4}{2n}.$
And so forth.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of intuition! I don't think I can do that on an exam! Lemme try this method with $1- (P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+...P(X=k))$.

Comment: I posted my solution for $1−(P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+...P(X=k))$ using the same method in **Edit 3**. It's not as pretty, but is it correct?

Comment: Sure, you can cancel out all the $2$s from the denominators in the book's answer, and then by applying the rule $a\cdot\frac{n - b}{n} = a - \frac bn\cdot a$ repeatedly to "simplify" the $\frac{n-(k-1)}{n}$ term, then the $\frac{n-(k-2)}{n}$ term, etc., you will get to the answer in Edit 3 (with the minor correction noted in my comment).

Comment: So for questions where like this where we are given a dummy variable $k$ in $P(X > k)$ instead of a constant, we should just try to solve it straight up using $P(X > k)$ instead of splitting it up since it offers no real benefit unlike $P(X > 3)$?

Comment: Even for relatively simple cases like $P(X>4)$ it seems simpler to compute it directly (product of just two fractions) rather than to compute $P(X=2),$ $P(X=3),$ and $P(X=4)$ separately so that I can subtract them from $1.$